# Why doesn't UDP return asynchronous error to application?

Tags: asynchronous, udp

In UNP v1, it says that if connect is not called upon a UDP socket, then this UDP socket will not return asynchronous error (like "port unreach") to up layer application. Its reasoning is listed in Section 8.9:

> A UDP client sends three UDP datagrams on a single UDP socket
>   to three servers on different hosts, then this UDP client calls recvfrom to wait for reply from these 3 servers. Suppose two of hosts are running the server, while the third is not running the server. So the third host will return a ICMP error with "port unreach" to this UDP client. And if recvfrom wants to return this ICMP error, it must tell client the destination IP/Port so that this client knows which datagram elicited the error. But since recvfrom can't return destination IP/Port to client on error, so recvfrom can't return this ICMP error as well, instead, recvfrom will block....

So after reading this, I can see the reasoning is that "because recvfrom can't return destination IP/port to caller on error, thus recvfrom can't return asynchronous error(port unreach)." But why can't recvfrom return destination IP/port on error? First, the ICMP message has included the IP header and UDP header, so kernel can know the destination IP/Port pair, second, the fifth and sixth argument to recvfrom can be used to return this IP/port pair to client application. It seems reasonable, right? So can anyone explain:

1. Why recvfrom can't return destination Ip/port to caller on error (like port unreach)?
2. Why recvfrom can't return asynchronous error (like port unreach)?

Comment: This isn't an answer to what you asked but I should caution you against relying on ICMP unless you are in control of the whole network between your client and server. ICMP is usually blocked by corporate firewalls to prevent port probing and other attacks.